# Split and mirror my desktop

Tags: desktop

I want to do something a bit specific (and I hope I don't have to write software for this).

I want to split my desktop screen into two (in just one monitor) and mirror it, so each will show the same content.

Why I want to do this? So I can get a tool like Splashtop and stream my divided screen to my google cardboard, showing my desktop in VR.

Any tips?

Comment: Might just be some specific GPU setting to do this. What's your system use for graphics?

Comment: I managed to do it with TrinusVR, doesn't mirror the desktop but does so when sending the signal to the phone. Recommended.